# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - Blender Python API

Tags: python, scripting, error

Hello Blender Community,

With my groupmate, we are working on a traffic simulation on Blender as our graduation project. Initially, the simulation engine runs and outputs a .txt file, *sim_log.txt*, containing the details to be processed by the script on Blender. Then, we run the script and get a visualization of the traffic flow.

Sometimes, I could not really figure out why, the Blender script throws the following exception when trying to read the output file which is in the same directory with the .blender file:

```
Info: Deleted 0 object(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\BlenderTest\CS402\SimulationAnimator.blend\Text", line 24, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sim_log.txt'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

The script up to the line that the error occurs is as follows:

```
import bpy
import os
import numpy
import random

#Test values
time = "day"

# Clean console, view and orphan data
os.system("cls")
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()
bpy.types.BlendData.orphans_purge()

# Set world background
if time == "day":
    bpy.data.worlds['World'].node_tree.nodes['Environment Texture'].image = bpy.data.images.load("//hdris\day.hdr", check_existing=True)
else:
    bpy.data.worlds['World'].node_tree.nodes['Environment Texture'].image = bpy.data.images.load("//hdris\\night.hdr", check_existing=True)

cameraCar = "" # Name of the car that camera will follow

# File read section
f = open("sim_log.txt", "r")
```

I mostly encounter this problem after another program accesses this file, but sometimes it occurs randomly. I could not find a way to tell Python API/Blender that the file actually is there, so I have been copying the file and updating the filename in the script. I thought the community could spot the problem, so I would not need to work with *sim_logv19.txt* anymore :)

If you would like to take a look at the project repository, here is the link:
https://github.com/sefasenlik/TrafficSim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think based on the Error that open is trying to load the file from the Blender project as a directory, but the project is a file and doesn't have this subdirectory "Text". You could probably fix this by using an absolute path and store the "sim_log.txt" in the same directory of the blender project. To get the absolute path you could use `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath), "sim_log.txt")`

Comment: Thank you, Rivin. It seems it worked, and I also think this can even be used as a generic solution for many relative path errors.
By the way, I guess I discovered that ending Blender's process on Task Manager resolves the problem temporarily.

Comment: If you agree with the answer, please accept it.